# Scaled $\epsilon$ in $\epsilon$-$\delta$ proofs

Tags: limits, continuity, proof-writing, epsilon-delta

When we are attempting to solve a limit or demonstrate continuity at a point through the $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definitions as in

$$
\forall \epsilon >0, \exists \delta >0 \; \text{ s.t. } \; \forall x \in A, |x-x_0|<\delta\implies |f(x)-f(x_0)|<\epsilon
$$
Sometimes we might encounter in the final step of the proof something like
$$
|f(x)-f(x_0)|<M\epsilon
$$
such that $M$ is a positive constant. I know that $\epsilon \in (0,+\infty)$ so it's closed under multiplication by a non-negative scalar $M$ and the $M$ doesn't affect the generality of the proof, however how should I explain this in the proof. Should I define $\epsilon'=M\epsilon$ or simply take $M^{-1}\epsilon$ at the definition?
It's a fairly simple doubt, but it bugs me.

Comment: You can do either. Introducing the $\epsilon$ in the hypothesis statement as $M^{-1} \epsilon$ is cleaner, but often reads in an "artificial" way, because it isn't clear to the reader yet why you're doing that (except in some very routine situations). Introducing $M$ later and then identifying $M\epsilon$ as your "$\epsilon'$" for the desired statement at the end is less artificial but a little bit less clean.

Comment: Construct a $\delta$ as a function of $\epsilon$ and show that your choice of $\delta$ implies that $|f(x)-f(x_0)|<M\epsilon$ where $M\in(0,1)$. So, $|f(x)-f(x_0)|<M\epsilon < \epsilon$.

Comment: (Cont.)  A third option, which is fairly similar to the second option, is to "Skolemize", meaning that you convert a $\forall x \exists y \, P(x,y)$ statement into $\exists f \forall x \, P(x,f(x))$. The advantage of this method is that you can use your statement to get $\exists \delta_1 \forall \epsilon \, |f(x)-f(x_0)|<M\epsilon$ and then define the desired function $\delta_2(\epsilon)$ as $\delta_1(M^{-1} \epsilon)$ at the end of the argument. This option is not very popular in mathematical writing in my experience however.

Comment: It depends on who you are. In an introductory analysis class, try to end your proofs with $\epsilon.$ If you're taking a more advanced course, everybody knows that ending with $642\epsilon^{1/3}$ is the same as ending with $\epsilon,$ and the professor will expect you to know that by now, and so will be fine with you skipping saying more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your proof should typically begin  with something like

> Let $\epsilon > 0$. Then if we take $\delta = \frac12 \epsilon^{1/3}$,  we have...

and end with something like

> ...so $|f(x) - f(x_0)| < 8 \delta^3 = \epsilon$.

(The expressions used are entirely made-up examples.)

If you have a slightly incorrect choice of $\delta$ depending on $\epsilon$, you might get a bound that's not $\epsilon$; for example, if we had chosen $\delta = \epsilon^{1/3}$ in this made-up example, we'd end with $|f(x) - f(x_0)| < 8\epsilon$. The correct thing to do in this case is to change your definition of $\delta$ at the beginning of the proof, so that we end with $\epsilon$ and not $8\epsilon$.

Usually you will not know what to pick for $\delta$ when you start out solving the problem. You will do some calculations in terms of $\delta$, and then you'll have to figure out how to begin your proof so that we get $\epsilon$ as the upper bound in the end. (Sometimes, you might write more complicated expressions like "take $\delta = \min\{\frac12 \epsilon^{1/3}, 1\}$".)

In a more informal setting, or if you're writing to an audience that is very comfortable with $\epsilon$-$\delta$ proofs, you might simply prove something like "If $|x - x_0| < \delta$, then $|f(x) - f(x_0)| < 8\delta^3$" and leave the $\epsilon$ implied.

Comment: If you define $\delta$ like that, $2\delta^3$ will not be $\epsilon$.

Comment: Whoops, fixed. Thank you!